# Show only errors and info, not warnings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the newer Chrome dev tools, you have an option to filter how noisy the console log is. It gives you these choices:

[image]

In the old version, we could *combine* filters. This was cool because it gave you greater control over the console logs - say you only wanted to show "Errors" and "Info", but not "Warnings", you would press on "Errors", then `ctrl-click` the "Info" button. Boom - done

[image]

So someone on the Chrome team thought this was too convenient, because it's now been removed.

My question is: How do I "revert back" to the old dev tools so I could get fine grained control over my filtering again? Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Interesting question-- the use case is probably relatively unusual but the new UI is definitely limited in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [big discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/kH3FiDLlsFg) on the topic in the mailing list.

In [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) you can [enable multiple levels, like before](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/kH3FiDLlsFg/3x7bFKJ3AAAJ).

Note that `console.log()` and `console.info()` are both grouped into the **Info** bucket.

Comment: Good answer and interesting discussion indeed. Perhaps switching to Canary is the way to go. Cheers.